# Showing all Network Adapters (connections) Icons in Windows 10 (and 7) System Tray (notification area, taskbar)

Tags: connection, icons, network-adapter, notification-area

I need to have all the icons to monitor all the active connections at a glance in the notification area (system tray) (Windows 10, 7..).

Currently, Windows shows only one icon, for only one of all the active connections.
In Windows 7 might be the Wireless one, in Windows 10 the Local Area one (e.g. similar situation TL;DR  https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/79235-how-display-wi-fi-icon-active-ethernet-connection-wi-fi.html).

I am connected to multiple networks (at least, let's say 1 Wireless and 2 Local Area connections).

How to show ALL the active connections icons in the notification area?
A behavior similar to Virtual Machines (e.g. VMware or Virtual Box) that show active connections in white and inactive ones in grey (or similar).
I would like only active connections with their current status.

I would really appreciate the help.
Thank you

Comment: I need to know if my Local Area connection has a problem even if the Wireless one is OK.
Sometimes I have Internet on Wi-fi and sometimes on the Local Area Network.
Problems occur frequently, and I need not to be distracted by the only one icon showing on top of all the others, showing most probably a status I actually need the less.

Comment: Is there maybe a little program that allows this functionality? There should be also for soundcards and sound applications.